# Decorator python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я не понимаю работу декораторов, что происходит когда внутри декоратора вызываем декорируемую функцияю а если не вызывать?  Что если, когда это делать при много декораторов, объясните их работу пожалуйста

Comment: Не хотите - не вызывайте, никто не заставляет.

Comment: Декоратор - это функция, которая принимает исходную функцию, и как бы добавляет ей дополнительное поведение (на самом деле возвращает новую функцию, которая внутри себя вызывает исходную функцию). Если не вызывать внутри исходную функцию, то по сути декоратор будет не добавлять поведение (не будет сохранять исходное поведение функции), а полностью изменять его. В этом случае проще написать новую функцию вместо декоратора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понимаю это так.

Когда файл выполняется (при import тоже происходит выполнение импортируемого модуля), то по **результату выполнения** в пространстве имен появляются разные функции, классы и так далее. В зависимости от нужных нам условий (например win/linux) мы можем конструировать нужные нам классы и функции.

Все эти def/class - специальные конструкции для создания "на лету" объектов функций и классов - и для этого вызываются внутренние механизмы для построения этих сущностей (в случае классов это встроенная функция type()).

И вот если встречается декоратор, то **при конструировании** объекта функции или класса (не путать с экземплярами) **дополнительно** вызывается функция декоратора, которой передается декорируемая функция/класс и с ними можно что-то сделать.

Обычно делают обертку над функцией чтобы контролировать доступ к функции, но на самом деле можно буквально сделать что угодно.

Например:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    class Foo:
        def run(self):
            print('i am class foo')
    return Foo


@my_decorator
def hello():
    print("hello!")

obj = hello()
obj.run()
```

Тут мы принимаем декорируемую функцию hello, игнорируем ее и конструируем класс.

А можем в декораторе сделать даже `return 1` и у нас вместо функции `hello` будет определена переменная `hello` типа `int` со значенем `1`

То есть декораторы являются возможностью вмешаться в механизм конструирования объекта и выполнить **любые** нужные нам действия.

Например, если мы пишем свой webapi, то можем сделать декоратор `@route('/api')`, который не будет ничего оборачивать, а зарегистрирует функцию в роутере, а если свой orm, то создаем маппинг для модели. А декоратор `abstractmethod` всего лишь добавляет к функции аттрибут `funcobj.__isabstractmethod__ = True` и ничего более.

Если же декораторов много, то вызваны они будут в обратном от определения порядке и каждой функции декоратора будет передан результат предыдущей

```
def my_decorator(func):
    return "a"

def my_decorator2(func):
    return 1

@my_decorator
@my_decorator2
def hello():
    print("hello!")
```

Первым будет вызван `my_decorator2` и получит как параметр функцию `hello`, а вторым будет вызван my_decorator и получит как параметр `int` (то, что вернула функция `my_decorator2`)

update: Подправил пост. Все-таки хоть декораторы и метаклассы по смыслу похожи, но декоратор получает уже сконструированный объект функции или класса, а метаклассы заменяют сам процесс создания.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь  все понятно